# Getting just a number out of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Witht the command

```
dummy1 = Position[Subsets[Range[n]], {3, 4, 5}]
```

I am getting a list of the form {{26}}. Is there any way to get just the number 26 as an output?

Thanks!

Comment: The output of `Position` is that format for a reason - it makes it compatible as input to other functions, regardless of dimensions of target. Just use `First@First@` or `[[1,1]]` on the result, or get sneaky and use something like `Max`. Take care that your `Position` is only going to return a single position (either from known structure of target, or adding the argument to `Position` to limit it to 1 result.)

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful!

Comment: Also see the documentation for `FirstPosition` if you are using version 10.0 or later; for example `FirstPosition[Subsets[Range[5]], {3, 4, 5}]` will return `{26}` as it does not need to allow for multiple matches (and does not take time looking for them), but the position is still a simple `List` because that is the generalized position format used by e.g. `Extract`.

Comment: Also, if what you're doing is getting positions (rank) of subsets, there are *much* more efficient ways to do this vs generating them and using position...